# TTreeView check all parents from child

Tags: c++, c++builder

This is a code that checks all childes when user check one parent. But how to check all parent checking one childe? By the way. I tried to use `Node->getPrevSibling();`but there is no effect.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::UpdateChildStates( TTreeNode *Node )
{
    int state = TreeView_GetItemState(TreeView1->Handle, Node->ItemId, TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK);
    int StateIndex = ((state & TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK)>>12);

    Node = Node->getFirstChild();
    while( Node )
    {
        Node->StateIndex = StateIndex;
        UpdateChildStates( Node );
        Node = Node->getNextSibling();
    }
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm1::TreeView1MouseDown(TObject *Sender, TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y)
{
  TTreeNode *Node;

  THitTests HitTests = TreeView1->GetHitTestInfoAt(X, Y);
  if( HitTests.Contains(htOnStateIcon) )
    Node = TreeView1->GetNodeAt( X, Y );
  else return;

  if( Node )
  {
    TreeView1->Items->BeginUpdate();

    try {
        UpdateChildStates(Node);
    }
    __finally {
        TreeView1->Items->EndUpdate();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Traverse parent nodes using `Node = Node->Parent;`

Comment: In this way are checked all below and under

Comment: If you e.g. click on a node, set its `StateIndex` and recursively traverse up the parents (setting each nodes `StateIndex`) it can't check any nodes under. Unless you do something wrong.

Comment: Do you mean to do in this way? ```Node = Node->Parent;
 while( Node )
 {
  Node->StateIndex = StateIndex;
  UpdateParentStates( Node );
  Node = Node->getPrevSibling();
 }```

Comment: Almost, but not. The call `Node = Node->getPrevSibling();` is superfluous if you want to visit chain of parents. Every node has only one parent. I don't understand why you would want to include siblings at any level, when traversing up the parents.

Comment: @Jacek `Node = Node->Parent; while( Node ) { Node->StateIndex = StateIndex; Node = Node->Parent; }`